# Why does my program crash after a few runs?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am fairly new to C++. My program seems to compile fine but it crashes every 4-5 runs. It seems to work fine for the first few runs, but after a while, I will get an error and my program will stop working.

This is what it tells me in the debugger, but I can't figure out which line is causing the crash. I believe I am not deleting the dynamically allocated memory correctly or trying to access a null pointer. I've been pulling my hair out but can't wrap my head around it.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int** test(int*, int);

int main() {
    int arr[3] = { 135, 3028063, 247777 };
    int** p = test(arr, 3);
    int count = 0;
    const int size2 = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < size2; ++i) {
        if (p[0][i] == 1) {
            cout << i << " occurs " << p[1][i] << " times." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}

int** test(int* ary, int size) {
    int i, j;
    int tmp;
    int** tmpAry;
    const int size2 = 10;
    tmpAry = new int*[size];
    int totals[size2] = { 0 };
    int* uncommons = new int[size2]();
    int** a = new int*[size2];

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tmpAry[i] = new int[size2 + 1]();
        tmp = ary[i];
        if (tmp < 0)
            tmp = -tmp;

        while (tmp != 0) {
            tmpAry[i][tmp % 10]++;
            totals[tmp % 10]++;
            tmp /= 10;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            if (tmpAry[i][j] != 0 &&
                tmpAry[i][j] == totals[j]) {
                uncommons[j]++;
                tmpAry[i][size2] += tmpAry[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        a[i] = new int[2]();
    }


    // pointers to parts
    int* array1 = a[0];
    int* array2 = a[1];

    // fill "arrays"
    for (i = 0; i < size2; ++i) {
        if (uncommons[i])
        array1[i] = uncommons[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i<size2; ++i) {
        array2[i] = totals[i];
    }

    return a;
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        delete[] a[i];
    }
    delete[] a;
}
```

Can anyone help point out my errors? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you mean to return a before deleting your arrays? Of course if that's the case then your deletion code will never run.

Comment: You really should switch to using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @NathanOliver I haven't gotten that far into the language yet, I am trying to get the basic foundations down before moving on to classes and vectors.

Comment: I would actually think you would do better learning about vectors first and then switching to pointers afterwards.

Comment: Maybe you should start with classes and vectors and later get into "basic foundations". `std::vector` is your bread and butter, pointers are an _"only if I have to"_ thing.

Comment: I think what Nathan is suggesting is that you may never get past the 'basic foundations' if you write code with [i,j,k] array indexing. mutiple stars, pointers and excessive new/delete.

Comment: An even more important thing would be to learn how to write small functions and use descriptive variable names, or more generally how to program in a structured way. Your code is completely undecipherable, does not communicate any intent whatsoever and practically cannot be understood without a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is writing out of bounds of array `a`. See, `a` is a 10x2 array.

```
const int size2 = 10;
int** a = new int*[size2];

for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
    a[i] = new int[2]();
}

int* array1 = a[0];
int* array2 = a[1];
```

`array1` is an array of size 2

```
// fill "arrays"
for (i = 0; i < size2; ++i) {
    if (uncommons[i])
    array1[i] = uncommons[i];
}
for (i = 0; i<size2; ++i) {
   array2[i] = totals[i];
}
```

there you write to `array1[2], array1[3], ...`. The same for `array2`.

There is a good chance that you have problems with memory corruption if your program crashes from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You never `delete` anything because you `return` before hitting that code.  So you have a memory leak which eventually crashes you program.  You'd be *much* better off using smart points, or better still one of the standard containers such as `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: Why would a minor memory leak crash an application with an access violation exception?